# Validate favicon on controller from form

Tags: php, laravel, validation, favicon, laravel-5.7

i want to validate my file, only .ico files.
Laravel dont include x-icon mime I think, how can i validate it?

```
  $logo = $request->file('logo');
  $favicon = $request->file('favicon');

  $request->validate([
    'logo'=>'image|mimes:png',
    'favicon'=>'',
     ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a custom validation rule as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules).

**In short:**

First do:

```
php artisan make:rule CheckIfFavicon
```

Then:

Create the validation code in the created Rules-file.

Try something like:

```
  public function passes($attribute, $value)
        {
            return $value->getClientOriginalExtension() == 'ico';
        }
```

Then ad it to the validation. Note, that if you make a custom validation class you will have to change the syntax in the $request->validate([...]) from pipe-ing to array.

```
$request->validate([
    'favicon' => [new CheckIfFavicon], 
]);
```

Comment: @Karoly I added some examples to point you in the right direction. good luck

Comment: how can i send $favicon to Rules/CheckIfFavicon?

Comment: where the files are inputed, in what I guess is a html input element. can you give them the name attribute <input type="file" name="favicon" ... > .  If you do it should be enough for laravel to understand to send that data to the rule if the validation rule looks like above

Comment: is actually <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="favicon">, file upload, works but no validate if is icon

Comment: then laravel sends the favicon-data to ChackIfFavicon by default?

Comment: no xd, sends it to controller but no to CheckIfFavicon

Comment: what do you get if u add dd($value) in begining of CheckIfFavicon

Comment: on line 29 change mime_content_type($favicon) to mime_content_type($value)

Comment: mime_content_type(): Can only process string or stream arguments xD

Comment: :) changed the validation. can u plz try that

Answer (score 0):

use `$file->getClientOriginalExtension()` in code if you only want to check file extension

```
$ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
if($ext == 'ico'){
  //uploadfile
}else{
  //do something else
}
```

use [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_file_uploading.htm) as reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom rule with the command below

```
php artisan make:rule RuleName
```

and you can add your custom rule as you want

in controller or request file you can call the rule throw

```
use App\Rules\RuleName.php
```

then call the validation rule you made in request file as

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'favicon' => [new RuleName],
    ];
}
```

or in controller will be like

```
$request->validate([
    'favicon' => [new RuleName], 
]);
```